# Can every even number $n \geq 8$ be written as a sum of a prime $p \geq \frac{n}{2}$ and a positive odd that is a non-multiple of $3$? (Part 2)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

This is part 2 of another question posted before.

**Problem**

Let $n$ be any even number equal to or greater than $8$. Then there exists a prime $p \geq \frac{n}{2}$
and odd $x>1$ that doesn't have $3$ as a prime factor, such that $n=p+x$.

Could anyone show a proof for this problem? Thanks

Comment: Either $2n-5$ or $2n-7$ must be prime to $3$.

Comment: Note:  your header question doesn't include teh requirement that $p≥\frac n2$.  Does $x$ have to be positive?

Comment: Yes, $x$ is positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n$ is large enough, yes.

Dirichlet's theorem gives a prime in any reasonable congruence class in large enough intervals, so in particular a prime $\equiv n-1$ or $n+1 \pmod 6$ in $[\frac n2, n-2]$. (Depending on which of $n-1, n+1$ is not divisible by $3$.)

Comment: What happens if $n$ is not large enough. Wouldn't it be true? (which would imply is not true for every even number equal to or greater than 8)

Comment: If you can find a version of Dirichlet's theorem in arithmetic progressions with an explicit error term, then you can quantify what 'large enough' means. Presumably, $n$ bigger than a million should be ok. And then you only have to check the $n \leq 10^6$ by hand. I can't find such an explicit error term right now, but someone certainly has done this. See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138048

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I have all the information I need.